# Copy of Rambam's Mishna commentary in Arabic online

Tags: halacha, minhag, rambam, mishna, arabic

Does anyone know where I can find Rambam's full commentary on the Mishna in the Arabic original or if it's Judeo Arabic online whether it's digital or manuscript form as long as it's not missing any letters and easy to read?

Answer (score 7):

You can access it online at the Judeo-Arabic part of the Friedberg Jewish Manuscript Society website. Go to the main website [here](http://fjms.genizah.org/), where you can sign up for free. Then go to the Judeo-Arabic site (bottom-middle button). Click the עיון button at the top-right, choose רמב״ם, choose the desired volume of פירוש המשנה, and click הצג. You can see the page image and/or copyable text via the options at the top-left (צילום and העתקה), and change pages with the arrows at the top.